# I have got microsoft jscript runtime error object expected

Tags: jquery

This is the section of site master:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.treeview.min.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.dialog.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/util-functions.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Scripts/clear-default-text.js")%>">
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this error?

Thanks.
Jyoti

Comment: I guess you dint mention the error you are getting .!

Comment: It's from the code in the js. If `util-functions.js` and `clear-default-text.js` is custom scripts post the code to check it. Venkat the error is in title of the post

Comment: @ pbaris you mean u need both js file code?